# unsigned long vm_pgoff in vm_area_struct

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I was reading the memory management chapter of Linux Device drivers and i came accross the **vm_area_struct** .The structure has an offfset field namely  **unsigned long vm_pgoff**  .

I checked the comment for the member as  `/* Offset (within vm_file) in PAGE_SIZE units, *not* PAGE_CACHE_SIZE */` . I'm not quite sure whether it is  the offset within the vma region or the offset in side the memory mapped file .

And i have seen driver's mmap implementation code to have the following line  to  recalculate the offset again by shifting the member by the **PAGE_SHIFT** bits .

```
unsigned long off = vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;
```

I'm not able to understand the same and any help on this would be great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code (file [mm.h](http://www.tsri.com/jeneral/crypto/include/linux/mm.h/source/SOURCE-mm.h.html)) of function

```
 static inline unsigned long do_mmap(struct file *file, unsigned long addr,
unsigned long len, unsigned long prot,
unsigned long flag, unsigned long offset)
```

I have found expression `offset >> PAGE_SHIFT` (right shift) that is used as `pgoff` parameter of `do_mmap_pgoff`, so it is obvious, to "restore" original `offset` value we need to do Left Shift with the same `PAGE_SHIFT` (as function `lowmem_page_address` do that).

Comment: I  didnt get the vm_pgoff field , what exactly is that field ?

Comment: I reread the thing clearly , the vm_pgoff field indicates the offset in number of pages ,that when right shifted by PAGE_SHIFT bits is same as multiplying 2 ^ PAGE_SHIFT with the number of pages which gives the total number of offset bytes .This is then further used in the calculations .

Comment: I think you have found the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

According to the book [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd edition](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1#chp-15-ITERM-7025),

> unsigned long vm_pgoff;
>
> The offset of the area in the file, in pages. When a file or device is mapped, this is the file position of the first page mapped in this area.

Thus, it is the offset, measured in number of pages, in the file/device. Thus, the first page in the vm_area is the page "vm_pgoff" of the file/device.

The file [mm_types.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L349) says the same.